# Update every h1 tag with 30 symbols (10 symbols from 3 paragraphs below h1 tag)

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, dom

So I have 12 paragraphs, these paragraphs are divided into four groups by three p tags. What I need to do is to get every three paragraphs 10 symbols (30 symbols total including space) and add its contact to h1 tag, need to do it 4  times, since there are 12 paragraphs by 3 groups.

```
 <div id="pastraipos">
 <h1></h1>
 <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
 <p>it is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted.</p>
 <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available.</p>
 <h1></h1>
 <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
 <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
 <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
 <h1></h1>
 <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
 <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
 <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
 <h1></h1>
 <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
 <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
 <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
 </div>
```

there are no h1 tags in html code, I just wrote it for you, so it could be more clear, since its hard for me to explain it.
So there is code, where I add h1 tag every 3 paragraphs:-

```
var parent = document.getElementById("pastraipos");
var children = parent.childElementCount;
console.log(children);
for (var i=0; i<=children; i=i+4){
var h = document.createElement("H1"); 
var t = document.createTextNode("Hello World"); //there should be no hello world it should contain 30 symbols from three paragraphs (10 from each including space)    
h.appendChild(t);
parent.insertBefore(h, parent.children[i]);    
}
```

This is a code that I wrote to get 10 symbols of each three paragraphs

```
 for (j=0; j<3; j++){
 var str = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[j].textContent;
 console.log(str);
 var res = str.substring(0, 10);
 console.log(res); 
    var labas = labas + res;
 }
 var s = document.createElement("H1"); 
 var t = document.createTextNode(labas);    
 s.appendChild(t);
 parent.appendChild(s);
```

This should appear in first h1

```
<h1>is simply it is a lot here are </h1>(30 elements total)
```

So I have code, that adds h1 tag every 3 paragraph, I have some piece of code, that collects 10 symbols from 3 paragraphs and add text to h1, sadly it only works on first h1, because somehow I need to combine these two loops? But I don't know how.

Comment: Why not use css with nth-of-type and ::after?

Comment: It has to be done with js and dom only, no css unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

H_ello f_riend, I'm not quite sure I did fully understand you but you can check if this code will help you -> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BQPygr?editors=1010

HTML:

```
<button onclick="doWork()">Run Function</button>
<button onclick="clearH1()">Reset</button>

<div id="pastraipos">
 <h1></h1>
 <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
 <p>it is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted.</p>
 <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available.</p>
 <h1></h1>
 <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
 <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
 <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
 <h1></h1>
 <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
 <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
 <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
 <h1></h1>
 <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
 <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
 <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
function doWork() {
  /* get all elements from the parent div */
  var children = document.getElementById('pastraipos').childNodes;
  var childrenLen = children.length;
  var childrenText = '';

  /* reverse loop */
  for (var i = children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (children[i].tagName === 'H1') {
      /* if element is <h1> set collected text */
      children[i].innerHTML = childrenText;
      childrenText = '';
    } else {
      /* assume element is <p> then get first 10 characters */
      childrenText += children[i].textContent.substr(0, 10);
    }
  }
}

function clearH1(){
  var children = document.getElementById('pastraipos').childNodes;
  for (var i = children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (children[i].tagName === 'H1') {
      children[i].innerHTML = '';
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

HTML:

```
<button onclick="doWork()">Run Function</button>
<button onclick="clearH1()">Reset</button>

<div id="pastraipos">
 <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
 <p>it is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted.</p>
 <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available.</p>
 <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
 <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
 <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
 <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
 <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
 <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
 <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
 <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
 <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
Element.prototype.remove = function() {
  this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
}

function doWork() {
  var parent = document.getElementById('pastraipos');
  var children = parent.childNodes;
  var childrenLen = children.length;
  var childrenText = '';
  var counter = 0;
  for (var i = children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (counter === 3) {
      var h1Element = document.createElement('h1');
      h1Element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childrenText));
      parent.insertBefore(h1Element, children[i]);
      childrenText = '';
      counter = 0;
    } else if(children[i].tagName === 'P') {
      childrenText += children[i].textContent.substr(0, 10);
      counter++;
    }

  }
}

function clearH1() {
  var children = document.getElementById('pastraipos').childNodes;
  for (var i = children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (children[i].tagName === 'H1') {
      children[i].remove();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how could i improve it and create h1tags with javascript, I mean i need to create h1 tags with javascript not in html, and i have that code already written, if you could check it and tell me how to combine, i would appreciate

Comment: Thank you man, one more thing, it doesn't display 30 symbols, it only displays 20

Comment: yes you were right I editted the codepen, now will edit the post, the mistake is in counter and insertBefore

Comment: @TautvydasBūda okay, now should work as expected, Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

> It has to be done with js and dom only, no css unfortunately

Here are two solutions. One using javascript and one using css. The script creates a header (h1) tag after each third paragraph (p) and displays the first ten characters from each of those previous paragraphs in it:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            //Creating dummy data
            function createDummyData(){
                var tF = document.createDocumentFragment();
                for(var i=0, j=100; i<j; i++){
                    var tP = tF.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
                    tP.innerHTML = 'Line' + i + ': and some more characters'
                };

                document.querySelector('div').appendChild(tF)
            }

            window.onload = function(){
                createDummyData(); //Creating summy data

                //Looping though all the paragraphs
                for(var tA=[], tL=document.querySelectorAll('.Blubb p'), i=0, j=tL.length; i<j; i++){
                    //Store the first ten characters
                    tA.push(tL[i].textContent.substr(0, 10));

                    //Each tenths step..
                    if((i + 1)%3 === 0){
                        //A header gets inserted
                        var tH = document.createElement('h1');
                        tH.innerHTML = tA.join('.. ');
                        tL[i].parentNode.insertBefore(tH, tL[i].nextSibling);
                        tA = [] //Empty the characters
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>

        <style>
            /* Alternativly this is a simple solution by merely using css, here marking each third element */
            .Blubb p:nth-of-type(3n+3):after{
                content: 'thid element reached by css';
                color: red
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class = 'Blubb'>
            <!-- Created by dummy -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9shfo5ge/2/